# Securing Windows Authentication on IIS

Tags: windows, security, authentication, iis

I have an internal system that verifies users automatically using their Windows credentials and then using LDAP to verify against the Active Directory

In IIS, I allowed "Windows Authentication" with 401 Challenge. So at first, the users had prompt for their Active Directory username and password whenever they launched the website:

[image]

Then I added "Authenticated Users" to the permissions list of that website folder in `C:/inetpub/ldap_website` and it now automatically recognizes them, and then the app itself verifies their credentials are matching and allowed to use in that specific area in the website.

But is there a way to secure it more?

Because I am not sure now - if the application pool is an MSA account, then when a Windows user authenticaes into the website - who actually runs the website? Under which user is it run? The MSA account, or now the Auehtenticated Windows user has his own process? So I'm a bit confused and would like to know if there's something I should do when using such method of authentication